# Does @AllArgsConstructor create constructor for static member?

Tags: java, lombok

For this class will @AllArgsConstructor create field for count?

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Money {
    private int paisa;
    private int rs;
    private static int count;
}
```

Comment: do you understand what static is, and why it's usually not linked to a constructor?

Comment: Lombok never generates constructor argument for the static fields for @AllArgsConstructor.

Comment: @stultuske  Yeah, static can be referred by class name directly, is created only once and initialized with zero or am I missing anything?

Comment: initialized with 0? that has to do with the datatype, not with whether or not it is static

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it will not.

See here: https://projectlombok.org/features/constructor

> Static fields are skipped by these annotations.